# Does Elementary OS 6 still support the same older hardware?

Tags: wifi, release-odin

I have an older 27" Intel iMac that worked just fine under Elementary OS 5, although the wireless internet did not work until after I performed the first set of updates.

Now, after wiping our the system and installing Elementary OS 6, even after installing all available updates, the wireless internet options is simply not available! The nly way I can use the internet is if I add an ethernet cable between the iMac and the router!

Furthermore, there is no longer and "about" link in the System Settings area!

Is support for the wireless in this older iMac now dropped? Or is there some other step or steps I need to go through to get the wireless internet to work?

Comment: Some iMacs have custom Broadcom chips that need a bit of work. Can you [edit] your question to include *which* iMac you’re using? The output of `sudo lshw -c network` and `sudo lspci` would also be useful, as this would show specific information about your network hardware 

Comment: krallen@iMac-946b3dfd:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for krallen:             
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff

Comment: lshw truncated - lscpi output too long?

Comment: If you [edit] your question, you can add the full output of these commands 

Comment: krallen@HantsCounty:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0111]